# Propagate / delegate path value to child routes akka http

Tags: scala, akka, spray, akka-http

I want to have a base route that receive a `IntNumber` and make some checks with the database to know if the values is correct or not and then If the value is correct I want to propagate the value to child routes.

**Base Route**

```
class BaseServiceRoute extends PathDirectives with SecurityDirectives {

  val baseUserRoute = pathPrefix("user" / IntNumber)

}
```

How can I make some checks for the value IntNumber and the delegate the value to the child route? Directives?

**Child Route**

```
class CategoryServiceRoute(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends BaseServiceRoute {

val route = baseUserRoute { userId =>
  pathPrefix("category") {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      get {
        complete(s"$userId")
      }
    } ~
      path(LongNumber) { categoryId =>
        get {
          complete(s"$categoryId")
        } ~
          post {
            complete("Hello category post")
          }
      }
     }
    }
   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best-practice suggestion would be just to nest the routes so that you can still access the value from the outer route like this:

```
pathPrefix("user" / IntNumber) { userId =>
  pathPrefix("category") {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      get {
        complete(s"$userId")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, you seem to want to separate routes into multiple parts which is perfectly fine. In that case just make the child route a `def`:

```
def childRoute(userId: Int): Route =
  pathPrefix("category") {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      get {
        complete(s"$userId")
      }
    }
  }
```

and then use it like this:

```
baseUserRoute(childRoute)
```